# unlink no funciona

Tags: php, laravel-5

Veran, tengo una tabla Foto con estos valores:

```
    Schema::create('fotos', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('foto')->unique();
        $table->string('nombre')->unique();
        $table->date('fecha');
        $table->unsignedInteger('categoria_id'); // Forarea de Categoria.
        $table->foreign('categoria_id')->references('id')->on('categorias');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id'); // Foranea de User.
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

La variable `foto` es la que almacena la imagen, que esta en `public/archivo`, y accedo a ella mediante esta variable:

```
public function ruta(){
    return asset("archivo/".$this->foto);
}
```

Resulta que quiero que tras eliminar una foto, se elimine tambien la imagen almacenada en la carpeta. Esta es la función:

```
public function eliminar(Foto $f){
        $f->limpiarImagen();
        $f->delete();
        return back()->with('message',['success',"La foto ha sido eliminada de la base de datos"]);
}
```

Y esta es la función que quita la imagen de la carpeta:

```
public function limpiarImagen(){
    if(file_exists($this->ruta()))
        unlink(public_path($this->ruta()));
}
```

Pero la imagen no se borra. ¿Como lo soluciono?

Comment: Has mirado que no sea un problema de permisos?? es una máquina windows?  a veces pasa que tienes que ser el "propietario" del archivo para poder borrarlo. Sí es este el problema, pasate a mirar la función chown de php. Haz también un if(unlink){echo 'ok';} else{echo 'mal';} a ver si es que no encuentra la ruta.

Comment: @cooper Pues era que el "asset" causaba un lío con las rutas. Ya lo he solucionado. ¡Gracias!